# File upload with ZF 1.9 resulting in no data

Tags: php, zend-framework, extjs

I'm currently using a mix of extJS4 and Zend Framework 1.9 (the user interface for the file upload page is programmed with extJS4, while the application itself is programmed with Zend Framework 1.9).

I'm currently running into the phenomenon, that the data I'm getting from the user interface looks correct, but the only way to even get zend framework to acknowledge that data has been sent to the php page is by using getRawBody(). 
isPost() results in true, but getPost() returns no data, also $_REQUEST returns no data at all.
I'm using $upload=new \Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();   in the program to process the incoming files.
But: $upload->getFileInfo(); also returns no data at all
(error logs of apache and php show nothing out of the ordinary.)

getRawBody returns me the following string (I've put it into the log file so can be that string(776) is part of my logging function):

```
string(776) "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------2384732604503
Content-Length: 667

-----------------------------2384732604503
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="combobox-1327-inputEl"

2
-----------------------------2384732604503
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filefield-1328-inputEl"; filename="mytest. - Kopie.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

testtest
-----------------------------2384732604503
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filefield-1329-inputEl"; filename="mytest..txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

testtest
-----------------------------2384732604503
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filefield-1330-inputEl"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------2384732604503--
"
```

My question here is what the reason for this behaviour could be (or if I'm doing something wrong here).
(As a Note: I'm using XAMPP with PHP 5.4 as Webserver)

I've now tried it out with another variant:

```
 <html>
  <body>
    <form action="/uploadmodule/index/save-upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Name: <input type="text" name="imageName" />
      Image: <input type="file" name="image" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I use this....all functions as it should...only when I use extJS4 uploadvariant it does not function.
Thanks

Comment: show us how to instantiate the form containing the item file?

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding you correct there. You mean how I "call" the form itself? (the "form" is part of an external extJS4 file that uses an AJAX call to upload the file and call my ZF-upload method). 

So would you need the AJAX call itself? Or the extJS part?

Comment: then you're not using a Zend_Form_Element_File: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/file-uploads-with-zend_form_element_file/?

Comment: No. The whole GUI is made solely with extJS4 (was a customer requirement). 

Another thing is.....when I use zend server as webserver it functions without problems. Also with an older xampp version and windows xp it functions (just testet it in the last few minutes).

On the machine where it is not functioning I'm running XAMPP version 1.7.7 in combination with win7 professional

Comment: then I do not know how to help you sorry!

Comment: No problem. Tnx for looking into it though. 
I'm pretty confused there why I have the problem myself.....it does not seem logical that I have the problem (especially as when I use ONLY php on the same machine it works fine....thus client and server side without extjs or zf)

Comment: I've solved it now. it was like in the post below a problem caused by a extJS parameter (interestingly even with firebug I didn't see anything out of the ordinary that could explain the behaviour, but at least problem solved now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved now. It was not a problem from the php side / zend framework side as I had originally suspected, but instead was caused by a parameter in the extJS code.

The phenomenon that $_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET was empty and only getRawBody() got the "Post" was caused by the following parameter set true:

```
Ext.data.writer.JsonView.prototype.encode = true;
```

As soon as the parameter was set to false:

```
Ext.data.writer.JsonView.prototype.encode = false;
```

The $_POST, ... was filled again.